# Arrange Columns in SSRS Matrix by Label by Percent

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset like in the image below. I have used a Matrix in SSRS to unpivot the data. 
[image]

What I have is like in the second image below. You will notice that percentage columns are at the far right. But what customers want is the name of a product followed by it percentage as seen in the last image. How do I accomplish this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: please edit your question and show your current design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a blank tablix to your report, drag the agent field into it and go to row groups and add a group. Group it by the field agent. Now add next to the agent field in the tablix your phone field and afterwards the percentage field. Now your data is grouped by agents like in your image and the fields are were you placed them.